Spectral bands of liquids and solids
I understand that instead of spectral lines, for solids and liquids spectral bands form, but why exactly do these bands form? I cannot see a reason why energy should be continuous now if photon emission is still discrete. I have seen explanations that look at the interactions of particles, yet how exactly does this result in a continuous band?
